# Entropy variation over a thermodynamic cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy, volume

How to calculate the entropy variation of a thermodynamics cycle that looks like a circle? The cycle is the same as in this photo

[image: picture]

Comment: Entropy is a state function, which means that it has a unique value for any given choice of P, V, and T.  If you return to the same point on your PV diagram, then the change in entropy is zero.  Do you mean to ask about the change in entropy over a *portion* of a thermodynamic cycle?

Comment: I ask about the change in entropy over all thermodynamics cycle. What I want is to demonstrate this with equations because this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, as @J. Murray said, if the initial state and final state is the same (as is the case for a cycle), the change in entropy of the working fluid is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reversible process, the change in entropy between two equilibrium states is given by

$$ \Delta S = \int \frac{dQ}{T} $$

where $dQ$ is the infinitesimal amount of heat which has been added to the system.  The first law of thermodynamics tells us that

$$ dU = dQ - pdV$$
so therefore

$$ dQ = dU + p dV$$
and

$$ \Delta S = \int \frac{dU}{T} + \int p\frac{dV}{T}$$

For a monatomic ideal gas,
$$ U = \frac{3}{2}NkT \rightarrow dU = \frac{3}{2}Nk dT$$
and
$$ V = \frac{NkT}{p}\rightarrow dV = \frac{Nk}{p} dT - \frac{NkT}{p} \frac{dp}{p} $$
so
$$\Delta S = \int \frac{3}{2}Nk \frac{dT}{T} + \int Nk \frac{dT}{T} - \int Nk \frac{dp}{p} $$
$$ = \frac{5}{2} Nk\log\left(\frac{T_f}{T_i}\right) - Nk\log\left(\frac{p_f}{p_i}\right)$$

This can be rearranged however you'd like using the ideal gas equation of state.  However, the point is that if you complete some reversible cycle such that $p_i=p_f$ and $T_i=T_f$, then the entropy change is equal to zero.

Comment: You should mention that this applies specifically to a mono atomic ideal gas.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes, you're right.  Added "monatomic."

Comment: But for a diatomic ideal gas?

Comment: Then you would need to adjust $U$ accordingly.

Comment: And now, what is the equation of U for diatomic gas?